# Field data inspection and collection using GeoODK?

Tags: data-collection, mobile-gis, open-data-kit, data-capture

In my workplace we are looking at collecting and inspecting GIS data using free mobile apps. The one that is fit-for-purpose from a data collection point of view is GeoODK. I have been able to prepare custom forms and get them to work in the field really well.

We already have GIS data in a proprietary GIS file format (shp, tab etc.) and we would like to inspect them on a mobile app.

Ideally, I would like to have this loaded onto an app and then have the inspections done by changing a few fields such as 'Inspection date', 'Inspection Officer' etc. and then capture new data along the way if these did not exist in the original GIS file.

Can this be achieved using GeoODK?

Comment: Don't forget to take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to the site and its protocols.  For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.  It would be fine to ask a focused question here about a specific concern you may have with whether GeoODK might meet your requirements.

Comment: Actually I can see a way to easily re-scope your question so I'll re-open it and do that now.